# Upgraded Grails project from 2.2.1 to 2.3.6 ; run-app fails with Tomcat, won't debug with Jetty

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, grails

A project that was running under Grails 2.2.1 and which I just upgraded to 2.3.6 (using GGTS 3.4 as our IDE) is having a very odd problem with 'run-app'.

If I use the tomcat plugin, which uses tomcat for dev runs, the grails run-app command appears to start tomcat, but fails to start the app. Any request sent to localhost:8080 returns a 404.

If I use the Jetty plugin, which uses jetty for dev runs, the grails run-app command starts normally, but never connects to the debug port in the IDE (yes, I have --debug-fork turned on).

A quickie sample grails app, made fresh in 2.3.6, runs correctly and as expected, so it seems it's got something to do with the version migration, or perhaps a piece of old configuration.

Has anyone seen an issue like this, and can you offer any suggestions for what I might not have fixed up appropriately during the migration? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your BuildConfig? I don't remember if you upgrade the fork block of code is copied...

Comment: Thank you, Sérgio. Have a look at this link [http://pastebin.com/v9Gm6BGR](http://pastebin.com/v9Gm6BGR) to see the current BuildConfig I'm working with.

Comment: Try to comment out the block : **grails.project.fork**

Comment: Thanks, Phat. I've tried that and it does not result in any change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Sharing it here for the benefit of anyone else who might hit the same problem:

When I successfully disabled forked execution, I saw a ClassNotFound exception being thrown by Tomcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.FilterDef
```

Searching on that error message found me this link: [Upgrade to tomcat:7.0.47 fails with web.xml issue](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Upgrade-to-tomcat-7-0-47-fails-with-web-xml-issue-td4652196.html)

The short version: If you have a file in your project called "web-app/META-INF/context.xml" with the following contents, you should delete it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Loader delegate="true"/>
</Context>
```

Do that and things should return to normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading from previous versions of Grails 2.3.x and you use the Hibernate and/or Tomcat plugins you will need to update the versions in BuildConfig:

```
build ':tomcat:7.0.50.1'
runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.8'
```

Check document : http://grails.org/2.3.6+Release+Notes

Comment: Thank you. The tomcat plugin is updated (see the pastebin link above) and my project does not use hibernate (MongoDB-GORM only)